# Can a theory be consistent but not $\omega$ consistent?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Say we have an axiomatizable theory $T$ extending $Th(A_E)$ where $A_E$ are the axioms of arithmetic. Is it possible to extend $T$ such that our extended theory is consistent but not $\omega$-consistent?

Recall that a theory $T$ is defined to be $\omega$-consistent if for each formula $\psi$, if $T \vdash \neg \psi(a)$ for each $a \in \mathbb{N}$, then $T \nvdash \exists b \psi(b)$.

Here are my thoughts: We need to add a formulas to $T$ such that for some $c$, we have $T \vdash \psi(c)$ and for all $a$, $T \vdash \neg \psi(a)$. I am not sure how it is possible to prove these two statemetns while maintaining that $T$ is consistent since we would have that we could prove $\psi(c)$ for some constant $c$ and $\neg \psi(c)$ since $c$ is in our domain. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that $A_E$ are the axioms on slide 5 of https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall03/G22.3033-002/lec/lec11_h4.pdf

Comment: How about PA plus an axiom saying that PA is inconsistent?

Comment: @bof you're right I will fix that

Comment: also @bof is PA plus the axiom saying PA is inconsistent necessarily a consistent theory? how should I go about proving that the new axiom does not disrupt consistency of the theory?

Comment: If $T+\alpha$ is inconsistent, then $T\vdash\neg\alpha.$

Comment: @Raton: PA + "PA is inconsistent" is indeed a consistent theory - this is the conclusion of Gödel's incompleteness theorem . But there is a simpler example. Start with PA and add a new constant $x$ and an infinite sequence of axioms of the form "$x > 1$", "$x > 2$", "$x > 3$", ... -  this theory is consistent by the compactness theorem. It proves $(\exists y) [y = x$, but it cannot prove $x = n$ for any natural number $n$, because of the extra axioms.

Comment: In your characterization of $\omega$-consistency in the last paragraph, you should say $T \vdash (\exists y)\psi(y)$, not $T \vdash \psi(c)$.

Comment: To expand a little on what Carl said about your last paragraph and address the understandable confusion you expressed, the "$c$" for which $\phi(c)$ holds will be a nonstandard integer in a model of the $\omega$-inconsistent theory in question. That's how it makes sense (from a semantic perspective) for the theory to prove $\exists x \psi(x)$ while at the same time proving $\lnot \psi(\mathbf n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

Comment: (cont'd) so It's best to separate the $T\vdash \exists y\psi (y),$ a simple statement about a proof existing in the theory, from the more meta-theoretical "finding a $c$" such that $T\vdash \psi(c).$ After all, when we assume the inconsistency of PA and add it as an axiom, we are just saying there exists a (godel number of a) proof of $0=1$ and adding this fact as an axiom... there's no actual proof there whose number we're adding. (Though models *can* be constructed of this theory, in accordance with what I said before).

Comment: We are assuming in all these comments that "consistent" really means "relatively consistent", that is, assuming that PA is consistent, then....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PA + "PA is inconsistent" is indeed a consistent theory - this is the conclusion of Gödel's incompleteness theorem .

But there are simpler examples. For instance, start with PA and add a new constant $x$ and an infinite sequence of axioms of the form "$x > 1$", "$x > 2$", "$x > 3$", ... -  this theory is consistent by the compactness theorem. It proves $(\exists y) [y = x]$, but it also proves $x \ne n$ for every numeral $n$, because of the extra axioms.

Comment: Compactness says for any set of axioms, there is a model for it iff every finite subset of the axioms has a model. How does this say anything about consistency which is about deductions?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the following assumes that the definition of $\omega$-consistency involves all formulas involving numbers, but it may sometimes be defined with respect to arithmetical formulas. All arithmetically sound theories are  $\omega$-consistent with respect to arithmetical formulas.

Whenever a set theory has surprisingly low consistency strength because of the compactness theorem, it tends to be $\omega$-inconsistent with the non-existence of the large cardinals that you would expect the theory to imply.

For example, let $T$ be the theory $\text{ZFC + "There is a correct cardinal}"$ where a cardinal $\kappa$ is [correct](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Reflecting) if $V_\kappa \prec V$ and we formalize this with a constant $\kappa$ in the language of $T$ and a schema saying that $V_\kappa \prec V$. Since $T$ is conservative over ZFC, $T+ \text{"There is no worldly cardinal"}$ is eqiconsistent with ZFC (and even [arithmetically sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) if ZFC is) but $\omega$-inconsistent because (in any model of this theory) the non-worldliness of $\kappa$ means that the model thinks that some axiom of ZFC fails in $V_\kappa$ but every standard axiom holds in $V_\kappa$ since $V_\kappa \prec V$. Thus $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent with any axiom implying that the class of wordly cardinals is non-stationary, where stationarity is defined with respect to the definable classes, or equivalently the classes of $\Sigma_n$-correct cardinals for every $n$.

Similarly, [Feferman theory](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Reflecting#The_Feferman_theory), the theory saying that the correct cardinals are unbounded (formalized with a predicate $C$, an axiom saying that the class $C$ is unbounded and a schema saying that every element of $C$ is a correct cardinal) is equiconsistent with ZFC but every extention saying that there are not [otherwordly chains](http://jdh.hamkins.org/otherwordly-cardinals/) of every finite length is $\omega$-inconsistent. If we take Feferman theory to include the axiom of replacement for formulas involving $C$, any extention  saying that there are not otherworldly chains of every ordinal length is $\omega$-inconsistent.

The Levy scheme, which says that there is a correct cardinal which is also inaccessible, is equiconsistent with [Ord is Mahlo](http://web.archive.org/web/20191005075336/http://cantorsattic.info/ORD_is_Mahlo), the theory saying that there is an inaccessible cardinal in every definable closed unbounded class, but Levy scheme + "There is no $\Sigma_\omega$-Mahlo cardinal" is $\omega$-inconsistent because if $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_n$-correct and inaccessible, the inaccessible cardinals are $\Sigma_n$-stationary in $V_\kappa$, so if $\kappa$ is fully correct and inaccessible, $\kappa$ is definably stationary with respect to the metatheory but the non-$\Sigma_\omega$-Mahloness of $\kappa$ means that the model thinks that there is a subset of $\kappa$, definable over $V_\kappa$, which contains no inaccessible cardinal.

$WA_0$, the weakest version of the [wholeness axioms](http://web.archive.org/web/20191104124240/http://cantorsattic.info/Wholeness_axioms) is equiconsistent with ZFC+ the schema saying that for every metatheoretical natural number $n$ there is an $n$-huge cardinal, as pointed out in [this MathOverflow answer by Dmytro Taranovsky](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319673/strength-of-btee/319674#319674), and thus weaker than the existence of a $\lt \omega$-huge cardinal (by which I mean one that is $n$-huge for every $n$, quantifying internally in the model) but $WA_0$+"The critical point of the wholeness embedding is not $\lt \omega$-huge" is omega-inconsistent since the critical point is $n$-huge for every standard natural $n$.